# Node.js Heroku process crashes

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

I'm trying to use heroku.com hosting for host a discord bot
So I tried to start the deployment and got no errors,

but if i go into the console i have this:

> 2021-09-06T14: 22: 20.024343 + 00: 00 heroku [web.1]: Process exited
> with status 1 2021-09-06T14: 22: 20.283616 + 00: 00 heroku [web.1]:
> State changed from starting to crashed 2021-09-06T14: 22: 20.288059 +
> 00: 00 heroku [web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
> 2021-09-06T14: 22: 24.651531 + 00: 00 heroku [web.1]: Starting process
> with command `npm start` 2021-09-06T14: 22: 27.056803 + 00: 00 app
> [web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start 2021-09-06T14: 22: 27.063092 +
> 00: 00 app [web.1]: 2021-09-06T14: 22: 27.063269 + 00: 00 app [web.1]:
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: 2021-09-06T14:
> 22: 27.063325 + 00: 00 app [web.1]: npm ERR!
> /app/.npm/_logs/2021-09-06T14_22_27_057Z-debug.log 2021-09-06T14: 22:
> 27.112489 + 00: 00 heroku [web.1]: Process exited with status 1 2021-09-06T14: 22: 27.182105 + 00: 00 heroku [web.1]: State changed
> from starting to crashed

So, the process crashed, in fact if I try to go here-> https://bouncerbotds.herokuapp.com I get an error. I honestly don't understand why since everything works correctly in my machine when I go to: `node .` with the same project.

Anyone know how I could solve?

Comment: Do you have a logging component in your app? If so you could review the app's log entries. Are you using the same version of Node in heroku as in your dev env?

Comment: @ScottGnile In what sense is the recording component? in my app I have installed firebase and other api such as axios for example. The node js version of my project is v16.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is super clear! You're missing a `start` script in your `package.json`, you might have initialised the deploy command as `npm start` in your Heroku `Procfile` although for it to run something it needs a default script which we call `start`, you may add it like this:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
}
```

You may look at [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#default-values) for understanding it better!